# Mouse event listener & "this"

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas, mouseevent

I'm now trying to register a mouse event listener on a canvas element.

As my JS application object initializes, it binds mouse events to a custom "MouseController" class:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',this.input0.btnDown, false);
```

"this" is the application object being initialized and canvas is a reference to the basic HTML5 canvas on my page.

The controller is a simple class like:

```
function MouseController(eventHandler) {
this.handler = eventHandler;

this.contact = false;

this.coordX = 0;
this.coordY = 0;
}

MouseController.prototype.btnDown = function(event) {
// Faulty line ???
this.updateCoordinates(event);
}

MouseController.prototype.updateHIDCoordinates = function (event) {
// code to set coordX and coordY of the controller instance
// Again, I can't access the object from here as "this" refers to the Canvas
}
```

As the mouse is clicked, the console logs "result of expression this.updateCoordinates' is not a function". A previous discussion taught me about the reference "this" being lost, ending up being bound to, in this case, the Canvas item.

So I'm looking for a way to call "btnDown" like I would in java, meaning that it executes as part of an object and thus has access to the variables of that object.

The only solution I found was a singleton... No good :( I'm sure there's a clean solution...
Please help :-)

Thanks!
J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create a closure:

```
var controller = this.input0;
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
    controller.btnDown(event);
}, false);
```

or use ECMAScript 5's [`.bind()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.input0.btnDown.bind(this.input0), false);
```

Also note that your other method is called `updateHIDCoordinates`, not `updateCoordinates`.

Comment: Weird thing now, as my btnDown is called, I make it call "this.handler.click()".
The "click()" method of the application object simply calls:
console.log('click at' + this.input0.coordX);
input0 was set as a member variable. Coming back from the controller, the "handler.input0" is set to null... any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm, now the reference to input0 works again.. .wierd... I certainly broke/fixed something without noticing. Thanks for your help!